# how to change the read destination of the data in the game

Tags: game-hacking

I would like to know how to change the read destination of the data in the game.

I now want to modify the player data and fonts in a psx baseball game.

However, the player data in the target game(called jikkyou powerful pro yakyuu premium ban) has a compressed data file (P_SC_M.BIN) and an uncompressed data file (P_SEL.BIN), and the one that is loaded in the game is compressed.

I can modify uncompressed data, but I can't modify compressed data.

So, in this case, I would like to know how to change the in-game data read destination from compressed data to uncompressed data.

Please let me know if you have any hints or information about useful tools.

Thank you.

Comment: Why not uncompress the data, modify it, and recompress?